# Java equivalent for PHP pack() function

Tags: java, php, base64, md5, pack

I have a PHP function. this code is to encryp a password

Is any one know how can I write this in Java code.

this what I was try but dont give me result.

```
    byte[] rawSHA = null;
    byte[] base64HexSHA = null;
    MessageDigest md= null;

    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        LOG.error("Unable to load MD5 Message Digest : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new IllegalStateException("MD5 Message Digest Instance Not Found");
    }


    rawSHA = md.digest(rawText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    base64HexSHA = Base64.encodeBase64(rawSHA);
    System.out.println("result = "+base64HexSHA );
```

Thanks for help

EDIT : 
I use this for base64 library

```
import org.apache.tomcat.util.codec.binary.Base64;
```

Comment: "but dont give me result." - please elaborate. What did you try, what did you expect and what did you get? Please also define which `Base64` class you are using as there are several libraries that provide one. It doesn't look like `java.util.Base64`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Solved this. this may help for other.

```
    String ps="tes";
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] encryptedPassword = md.digest(ps.getBytes());
    byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(encryptedPassword);
    String Str2 = new String(encodedBytes);
```

give me a result :

```
before =tes
after :KLZi2IO212/Zbk3cXpungA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String someString = "qwe";
MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
String checksum = new BigInteger(1, messageDigest.digest(someString.getBytes())).toString(16);
System.out.println(checksum);
```

Hope this helps .. :)

Comment: I try input =[12345abc]. this the result : from your code [185aef3b1c810799a6be8314abf6512c], from php function above [GFrvOxyBB5mmvoMUq/ZRLA]

Comment: `185aef3b1c810799a6be8314abf6512c` value is correct MD5 for input `12345abc`. you are comparing the outout with MD% or with the return value of your method `md5_base64($txt)`?

Comment: yes this`s correct with MD5 encryp. but the php function above is not just encryp input text into MD5 encryption. there a replace string and pack function inside